# Combining frequency tables in R

Tags: r, merge, data-processing

I have a vector containing the frequencies of molecules within their respective molecular class for all molecules measured. I also have a vector that contains the per class frequency of significant molecules identified by variable selection. How can I merge these 2 vectors into a data frame and fill in empty frequencies with 0's (in R)?

Here is a workable example:

```
full = rep(letters[1:4], 4:7)
fullTable = table(full)
sub = rep(letters[1:2], c(2, 4))
subTable = table(sub)
```

I would like the table to look like:

```
print(data.frame(Letter=letters[1:4], fullFreq=c(4, 5, 6, 7), subFreq=c(2, 4, 0, 0)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (I supposed you meant `subTable=table(sub)` in your last line):

```
 res<-merge(as.data.frame(fullTable),as.data.frame(subTable),by.x=1,by.y=1,all=TRUE)
 colnames(res)<-c("Letter","fullFreq","subFreq")
 res[is.na(res)]<-0
```

Answer (score 0):

With the library `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

full=rep(letters[1:4], 4:7)
sub=rep(letters[1:2], c(2,4))
df <- data.frame(Letter=unique(c(full, sub)))


df <- df %>% 
     left_join(as.data.frame(table(full)), by=c("Letter"="full")) %>% 
     left_join(as.data.frame(table(sub)), by=c("Letter"="sub"))

df[is.na(df)] <- 0
df
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, dimities_ps. It works great, but I am going with nicola's answer simply because it doesn't require an additional package.

Comment: Sure no problem. You should look into `dplyr` eventually, it does some complicated things ...easy.